# Converting a responseEntity to httpServletResponse with spring

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

My controller method looks like this :

```
public void doLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
```

and I want to do this

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(testPrefix + "/login", map, String.class);

response = responseEntity;
```

or similar, basically make a restcall and return the HttpReponseEntity as the response n its enitirety

Comment: Can you please clarify. Are you saying that within the doLogin() method, you wish to call restTemplate.postForEntity() and then return that as the response from doLogin()?

Comment: An interesting question, but also my question is that let's say you have this converter from `ResponseEntity` to `HttpServletResponse`; what's the use case?

Comment: @nobeh don't ask, its not my decision. But I am returning ResponseEntity as the responsebody, seems to do the job

Comment: There is a use case when overriding certain spring handlers. For example when setting a custom exception handler in `WebSecurityConfig` with `HttpSecurity.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(...)` I have to override such a method. It would be nice to have some kind of translator for this instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 2):

From updated comments I assume that you are wanting to return the result of the `restTemplate.postForEntity()` call from your Controller.

As shown by the [Spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-httpentity), ResponseEntity is a valid return type from a Controller method. So you can simply return the result of your `restTemplate.postForEntity()` call from the `doLogin()` method. As an example:

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
     @AutoWired
     private RestTemplate restTemplate;

     @RequestMapping("/yourPath")
     public ResponseEntity<String> doLogin(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
     {
          return restTemplate.postForEntity(testPrefix + "/login", map, String.class);
     }
}
```

Spring MVC will take care of marshalling the `ResponseEntity` into the HTML response using a `HTTPMessageConverter`.